# Control click keyword (AutoIt - Robot framework) is not actually clicking the menu option from notepad

Tags: robotframework, autoit

I am trying to click File menu of notepad using robot framework and AutoIt. It's not actually doing the click, but the test case is getting passed. The below is the code snippet.

```
Control Click   Untitled   ${EMPTY}   File1
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you've already tried?

Comment: I need to click the File-Menu option alone from notepad through AutoIt robotframework. AutoIT v3 spy is not able to find the details of the menu bar. I am guessing that File1 is not a proper control ID. Kindly letting you know that I do not want to click any of the menu items under File (New, Open etc). I want to replicate this for my application which has a menu called 'Events' and no hot keys been assigned to it and has no menu items under it either. I am seeing a similar behavior for my app where AutoIt spy is not capturing the menu bar objects. I am now using mouse click to attain this.